# HTML POST form submit is mangling URL

Tags: php, html, forms

I am trying to get a HTML/PHP form to submit properly. Some details:

base url = `http://localhost/directory`

page = `page/add`

complete address = `http://localhost/directory/page/add`

Using htaccess to rewrite urls so `http://localhost/directory/page/add` is actually `http://localhost/directory/index.php?q=page/add`

My HTML POST action is "page/add" so that the front controller knows which function to fire to sanitize and submit the data (it acts as a 'form id').

The page loads fine at http://localhost/directory/page/add but when I click on the submit button, the URL gets mangled to page/page/add. And every time I press "submit" I get another "page" added to the url. So 5 clicks will get "page/page/page/page/page/page/add"

I can't seem to find why I am getting that "extra" "page".

The actual PHP error (page/page/add doesn't exist in $routes since it isn't a valid route):

Notice: Undefined index: page/page/add in C:\xampp\htdocs\script\includes\common.inc on line 92

Here is the function at line 92:

```
function route_path($path = NULL) {

    $routes = get_routes(); //Returns array: approved "urls => function callbacks"

    if($path === NULL) {
        $path = get_path(); //Returns $_GET['q'] with trim and strip_tags
    }

    $function = $routes[$path]; <<<<<----This is LINE 92 

    if(isset($function)) {
    $form_name = str_replace('/', '_', $path); // page/add = function page_add()
    }

    if(function_exists($function)) {
        call_user_func($function, $form_name);
    }
    else {
        //TODO: Redirect to Login screen.
    }
}
```

The basic HTML is:

```
<form action="page/add" method="post" />

//Form elements

<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Thanks for the help.

**UPDATE**: What I did was add the `<base>` tag to my HTML templates. This allows me to keep the action as page/add (since it is also a route in my simple router/dispatcher).

Comment: What is the URL of the form?  You know that `page/add` is relative to the current?  This will be different if the URL of your form does or doesn't end with a `/`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using a *relative path*, you're telling the form to submit at the *existing path plus your action*. So if you are at http://example.com/page/add, the form uses `http://example.com/page/` as a base and adds the action `page/add` resulting in a POST to `http://example.com/page/page/add`.

You can still use a relative path, just change the action accordingly:

```
<form action="add" method="post" />
```